# GNU make rule order/preference

Tags: makefile

I have two wildcard rules like so:

```
%important_results/output.pdf: input2.o
    SETTING=$* myimportantcommand > $@

%results/output.pdf: input1.o
    SETTING=$* mycommand > $@
```

with simple prerequisites:

```
input1.o: input1.c
    touch input1.o
input2.o: input2.c
    touch input2.o
```

However, I am getting varying behaviour when I run `make important_results`:

- if input2.o exists, it uses the `%important_results` rule
- if input2.o does not exists, but input1.o exists, it uses the `%results` rule instead of building input2.o. However, this runs the wrong command.

How can I give make a rule preference, so it always goes with `%important_results` rule even if it has to build prerequisites?

Searching for "gnu make rule order" or preference did not yield anything.
I suppose the simplest solution is to use non-overlapping wildcards.

**edit**: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html suggests that stems cannot be applied to directories in this way.

Comment: I'm getting strange results when I try to reproduce this. What version of Make are you using?

Comment: this is with GNU Make 4.1

Answer (score 0):

GNU make manual:

> The target is considered a pattern for matching file names; the ‘%’
> can match any **nonempty** substring, while other characters match only
> themselves.

Try the following, maybe:

```
%mportant_results/output.pdf: input2.o
    SETTING=$(patsubst %i,%,$*) myimportantcommand > $@
```

Demo:

```
$ ls
Makefile input1.c input1.o input2.c
$ make important_results/output.pdf
touch input2.o
SETTING= myimportantcommand > important_results/output.pdf
```